# Remove invalidated marker

Tags: here-api

I have a `H.map.Group` with a bunch of markers.

If i need to remove a single marker i run:

```
this.markerGroup.removeObject(marker);
```

But sometimes in other part of my code i run:

```
this.markerGroup.removeAll();
```

So if after i run single marker remove method it throws me an error, because there is no such marker on `markerGroup` layer because all markers were removed previously.

How can i know the marker is valid and exists on a map so i can remove it correctly?

In Yandex Maps i have `isValid` method so i can validate marker before making some actions with one:

```
marker.isValid && markerGroup.remove(marker);
```

If `isValid` is `true` it means the marker has geometry and it is on a map, if `false` means the marker just exists in memory and not attached to the map.

What is equal functionality in Here maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[H.map.Marker#getParentGroup()](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map-marker.html#h-map-marker__getparentgroup) or [H.map.Marker#getRootGroup()](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map-marker.html#h-map-marker__getrootgroup) should work for that case.